# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice' error

Tags: python

I built a music bot but I have made a mistake.

The error I get is exactly like this;

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice'
```

commands;

```
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url : str):
    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice.channels, ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
    voice = discord.utils.get(Bot.voice_clients, guild)
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    guild =  ctx.guild
```

Comment: More context might be needed to answer your question. The only thing we can definitely tell is that whatever `ctx.guild` in the first line of your `play` function is, it doesn't have an attribute `.voice`, but it's not very helpful since it's basically what the error message says. Including more code (particularly the definition of `ctx`) can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.voice_client,ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
```